# Notice: Array to string conversion in {Error}

Tags: php

I have to make a directory and save the file, but there is an error that written in title. Help me to solve this error. My code is below.

```
  function main() {
      $scrapper = new Cloaked_Scraper();
      // Prefix of URL's
      $url_prefix = "link";
      // URL
      $urls = array("www.something.com?");
      // Get ID from every URL and will save on index one of $url array
      $urls[1] = ((explode("www.something.com?id=com.", $urls[0])));
      $urls[0] = $url_prefix;
      $urls[0];
      $urls[1];


      //mkdir("../temp/", 0777 /* The mode is 0777 by default, which means the widest possible access */);

      // Destination folder where this file will save, and file name.
      $output_dir[0] = "../temp/".$urls[0].$urls[1].".html";
      $results = $scrapper->fetch($urls, $output_dir);
      var_dump($results);

    }

    main();
```

Comment: Full Error Message please (with linenumber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `Cloaked_Scraper` is, but it seems that its `fetch` method only accepts a string as its first or second parameter. You pass an array to both of them.

I think `$output_dir` needs to be a normal string, but by assigning to `$output_dir[0]` you implicitly make it an array.

Change that line to this and see what happens:

```
$output_dir = "../temp/".$urls[0].$urls[1].".html";
```

But in general, I think your code is very confusing. It seems like you are recycling items of the `$urls` array while you should actually use separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$urls[1] = ((explode("www.something.com?id=com.", $urls[0])));
```

explodes a String to an Array of strings, in detail, `$urls[1]` contains: `array( '', 'id=com');`

You now try to insert this Array as a this Line:

```
$output_dir[0] = "../temp/".$urls[0].$urls[1].".html";
```

Just use the correct index for the String:

```
$output_dir[0] = "../temp/".$urls[0].$urls[1][0].".html";
```